# WP REST API and React Native: how to show content not in HTML

Tags: android, ios, wordpress, react-native, wordpress-rest-api

Simple (i'm sarcastic) question: is there any way to display CONTENT of wordpress post (that REST API returns as HTML) in a simple View or something? With line-break, strong etc?

Something that i can do to change the API RESPONSE or to manipulate the result in React Native?

I've looked at WebView, https://github.com/archriss/react-native-render-html and a lot of other things.

Comment: i'm also looking for the solution of same problem

Answer (score 0):

A possible work around is to make a custom endpoint to send your markup as a string, and then parse it on the client.

Here is an example of an endpoint where I map my post titles to an array of h3's.

```
function postsAsHTML(){
$data = array();

$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'posts_per_page' => '12',
);

  $posts = new WP_Query($args);
?>

<?php if ($posts->have_posts()): ?>
  <?php while ($posts->have_posts()) : $posts->the_post(); ?>
        <?php
            global $post;
            $html = "
                <div>
                    <h3>" . html_entity_decode(get_the_title()) . "</h3>
                </div>
            ";
            array_push($data, trim($html));
        ?>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif;

return array(
    'data' => $data
);
}

// Register the rest route here.
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'YOUR_NAMESPACE/v1', 'posts-as-html',array(
        'methods'  => 'GET',
         'callback' => 'postsAsHTML'
   ));
 });
```

I'm sure you could also change the response header to send markdown directly. Regardless hopefully this helps!